# Selenium - Store hidden variable

Tags: java, junit, selenium, selenium-ide

We are using Junit + Selenium to webtest our webpage. But we have run into a problem.

I need to parse the value from a hidden field with Selenium.
HTML of hidden field
`<input type="hidden" name="secretId" value="123456"/>`
I use the following XPath
`//input[@name='secretId']/@value`

I need to scrape that hidden variable and store it using a XPath and use it further on down the script.

How do I do this with Selenium?

I have tried

`String secretId = selenium.getText("//input[@name='secretId']/@value");`
 
Returns empty string

`String secretId = selenium.getEval("//input[@name='secretId']/@value");`
Returns null

The XPath is correct, I have verified this with XPath Checker in Firefox

Thanks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer
`String secretId = selenium.getValue("//input[@name='secretId']");`

Comment: How can I get the value by using WebDriver?

Comment: I don't know about Java, but this works in Python and might as well i Java: driver.find_element_by_name('something').value = 'some string'

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer to get the value by using WebDriver:

String secretId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='secretId']")).getText();